# Configure bitbucket integration with Axosoft OnTime

Tags: git, project-management, bitbucket, ontime

How can I configure my Axosoft OnTime account to works with my BitBucket account.

I've found the "Add:Source Control Type" wizard but there's no documentation about it

Also, how can I configure a custom Hook in my bitbucket account to post to OnTime?

Answer (score 1):

Axosoft has an integration with [zapier](http://www.axosoft.com/integrations).  I have confirmed you can build out a zap that triggers a post of commit data to any of your tagged items.  Works a lot like [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) if you have ever messed around with that.

Hope that helps,

:)